# QWidget has not attribute setWinowTitle

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

```py
import sys 

from PyQt4.QtGui import * 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()
w.resize(250,150)
w.move(300,300)
w.setWinowTitle(('hey'))
w.show()


sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "gu.py", line 9, in 
> w.setWinowTitle(('hey')) AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'setWinowTitle'

I am using Windows and installed pyqt using t binary installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in right way :)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Hey')
        self.show()

def main():
    qtApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = ExampleWidget()
    sys.exit(qtApp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And avoid importing using * its not good practice

As request here is the working version of your code.

```
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()
w.resize(250,150)
w.move(300,300)
w.setWindowTitle(('hey'))
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You had aa typo setWindowTitle not setWinowTitle :) and you declared QApplication as app and you were exec with a.

Comment: Thanks that really helps.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify my program and get an out, because the code i am using is from simple learn and it works fine on the user's system who teaches python.

Comment: if the answer helped please choose as answer and up vote :)

Comment: Thanks That really helps :)

Comment: Please see my about comment :)